# Convergence in probability for a given distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, convergence

$X_n$ assumes the values $1 , \frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{3}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}$. with equal probability . Examine whether  $X_n$ converges in probability to some constant?

This is what I tried :

$\mathrm{E}(X_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$, here I am confused how to solve limit $n \to \infty$ on RHS.

Comment: Compare the sum to $1 + \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x} = 1 + \log(n).$

Comment: Does $E(X_n)$ help in proving convergence? I think it is clear as to which constant it may converge and then simply use the definition of conv. in probability.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad i didnot got what you say. please explain more

Comment: To continue with your approach, we have for large $n$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\approx \int\limits_1^n\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\ln n$, so that $E(X_n)\to 0$. Similarly $E(X_n^2)\to 0$ and since both limits exist, $\operatorname{Var}(X_n)\to 0$. So the limiting expectation and variance of $X_n$ together imply that $X_n$ converges in probability to zero (by a sufficient condition).

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question because it helps expose the meaning of convergence in probability and thereby develops our intuition.

**When probabilities are involved and the question is general, the most basic tool to consider is the cumulative probability function, or CDF.**  For any number $x$ its value at $x$ is

$$F_X(x)= \Pr(X \le x).$$

This is useful because convergence in probability can be established by showing that the sequence of CDFs converges to some limiting CDF *except possibly at points where the limiting CDF has jumps.*

**Take a look at the CDFs of some of the random variables $X_n$ in this sequence.**

[image: Figure]

To reflect the probabilities of $1/n$ at the values $1/n, 1/(n-1), \ldots, 1/2, 1/1,$  the CDF of $X_n$ has a vertical jump of $1/n$ at each of those numbers. As $n$ grows, those jumps get smaller but they also concentrate close to $0,$ since $1/n\approx 0$ for large $n.$

For reference, I have drawn the CDF for a constant jump of $1$ at the value $0$ with a dashed blue line.  This is the CDF for the constant, or "atomic," random variable that is always zero.  Let's call this CDF $F_0.$ *The CDFs of the $X_n$ appear to be approaching $F_0.$*

---

To *prove* that the CDFs of the $X_n$ do approach $F_0,$ first consider any positive number $x.$  The value of $F_{X_n}(x)$ is $1/n$ times the number of jumps made at values less than or equal to $x.$  These would be the integers between $1/x$ and $n,$ inclusive.  Writing $[1/x]$ for the smallest integer exceeding $1/x,$ we have shown that

$$F_{X_n}(x) = \frac{n - [1/x] + 1}{n}\tag{1}$$

provided $n \gt x,$ which eventually will occur no matter what value $x$ might have.  As $n$ grows large, the fraction in $(1)$ approaches $1$--just as the figure suggests.

Next, if $x \lt 0,$ $F_{X_n}(x)=0$ is a constant sequence with the limiting value $0.$

**Putting these results together establishes two limits:**

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(\epsilon) = 1$ for positive $\epsilon.$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(\epsilon) = 0$ for negative $\epsilon.$

*We don't care about what happens at $x=0$ because $F_0$ has a jump there.*

Consequently, we have established that

> $F_0$ has a jump at $0.$  For all $x \ne 0,$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(x) = F_0(x).$ Therefore $\operatorname{plim}_{n\to\infty} X_n = 0.$