# Example of convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, convergence

[image]

I found a problem in taking the limit (when $X= 1$), this is what I am getting:

$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}F_{Xn}(x) = $$F_X(x):= \begin{cases} 1\,, &\text{ if } x>1\\ \frac {1}{2}\,, &\text{ if } x=1\\ 0\,, &\text{ if } x<1\end{cases}$

Please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the definition of limit in distribution, the value of the limit when $x=1$ (at the jump point) is immaterial, it is not used in the definition.

Comment: Very closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265047.  (In that case the limiting distribution is the same as here but the pointwise limit of the CDFs at $x=0$ is $0.$)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a small aspect of the definition of convergence in distribution that is crucial in this particular case.  The requirement for convergence in distribution is that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}(x) = F_X(x)$ should hold at all values of $x$ *where $F$ is continuous*.  It is okay if the limiting equation does not hold at points of discontnuity of the distribution function $F$.  In the particular case you are looking at, the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}(x)$ is not even a [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) because it is not right-continuous.  Nevertheless, it is equal to the cumulative distribution function $F$ at all the points of continuity of the latter.

You might be wondering why it is useful to define "convergence in distribution" in this way, without requiring the limit to hold at all points.  To see why this is a good definition of the concept, it is worth looking at the famous [portmanteau lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures) (showing various equivalent requirements for weak convergence of measures).  This result shows that there are several equivalent kinds of convergence of measure, and one of these is the requirements for the limiting equation here to hold for all points of continuity of $F$.  If you were to add a stronger requirement (i.e., requiring the limit to hold at all values of $x$) then this would be in excess of what is required to establish the other types of convergence of measure used in the portmanteau lemma.

Answer (score 0):

We are to show convergence to a degenerate distribution at 1. We might write the cdf as $F(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ if } x <1\\ 1 \mbox{ if }x \ge 1 \end{cases}$.

Since this cdf is equal to yours except at a countable number of points (one). There is nothing left to show.