Empirical distribution and dirac delta question
According to a book I'm currently reading (Deep Learning by Bishop), The empirical distribution can be defined as
$\displaystyle p(x|D) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \delta(x-x_n)$
where $D$ is a set of finite samples drawn from the density $p(x)$.
As $\delta(x-x_n)$ is defined to be infinite when $x = x_n$, I assume that $p(x=x_n|D)$ is has the same "height of the peak" regardless of $n$. (Maybe here is where my intuition breaks)
When we sample more and more from $x$, how can $\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} p(x|D) = p(x)$?

You need to understand, what is meant by convergence. The best way for this is to look at the "Glivenko–Cantelli" theorem, which discusses this.

The shallow learning version says that $p(x)$ is not a (probability)  density function but a probability mass function, and your displayed formula is saying that the empirical distribution of $X$ igiven the data s a discrete distribution saying that $X$ takes on values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ with equal probability $\frac 1N$.  The unconditional distribution of $X$ might or might not be a discrete distribution.  Incidentally, the Dirac delta is not a function, and $\delta(x-x_n)$ cannot be defined th be infinite when $x=x_n$.

$\delta$ is not a function and has no "height."  For one account of how to conceive of $\delta,$ see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/73626/919, found as the first hit in a search of our site for Dirac Delta.  For making sense of limits of distributions you must use the general definition of distribution (as giving a probability for arbitrary measurable sets) rather than the limited characterization of it in terms of the PDF $p.$

My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/412524/919 illustrates convergence in probability for this case.
